# Cannot find data type geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I can't seem to be able to use the geography column type it's meant to have.  It doesn't show up in the data type column when I create a new column and when I run this code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Core].[Address2](
 [Geo_Id] [geography] NULL);
```

I get

> Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type geography.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to enable the new data types somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, I'd double check to make sure the database you're using is indeed on a SQL 2008 instance.

Comment: No you're right. I'm at a new company and because I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio to manage the database I assumed all the databases would be stored in 2008 too. Stupid me. Turns out they're all 2005, should've double checked there first. Thanks for you answers

Answer (score -1):

I have found that when you add a geography column you need to restart the Management Studio in order for it to appear in intellisense. This might be the issue you are having perhaps?

Comment: No its not appearing at all to add it. It's like it doesn't exist full stop